# How do I solve $ \int_{-1}^{1} \cos^2(3\pi t) dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this integral: $$ \int_{-1}^{1}\cos^2(3 \pi t) dt$$

I don't remember the specific rules for solving this... I would find the primitive function to the above, but I don't know how to combine the square and the inner value.

If I had $f(x)=\cos(3\pi t)$ then the primitive function would be $F(x)=\frac{-\sin(3\pi t)}{3\pi}$ I think, but how does the square affect this?

Comment: You get rid of the square by using this identity: $\cos^2\theta=\frac12(\cos2\theta+1)$.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to find the primitive. By the duplication formulas:
$$\cos^2 x = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos(2x) $$
hence:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\cos^2(3\pi t)\,dt = \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dt}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\cos(6\pi t)\,dt,$$
but the second integral in the RHS is zero due to the periodicity of the integrand function.

Answer (score 1):

From a plot of the function you see that the function oscillates symmetrically around its average value $\frac12$ and the integration range covers full periods.

Hence the integral value $$2\cdot\frac12=1.$$

---

Anyway, you can also address the problem directly. You need to find a function such that the derivative is the square of a cosine. First try the given function
$$\left(\cos^2(3\pi t)\right)'=-2\cdot3\pi\cdot\cos(3\pi t)\sin(3\pi t).$$
Not what we want, but we notice that the product of two trigonometric functions gives the product of two trigonometric functions. So let's try with the latter product

$$\left(\cos(3\pi t)\sin(3\pi t)\right)'=-3\pi \sin^2(3\pi t)+3\pi\cos^2(3\pi t).$$
Not yet what we want, but we can get rid of the squared sine
$$-3\pi \sin^2(3\pi t)+3\pi\cos^2(3\pi t)=-3\pi\left(1-\cos^2(3\pi t)\right)+3\pi\cos^2(3\pi t)=6\pi\left(\cos^2(3\pi t)-\frac12\right).$$
Putting it all together,
$$\left(\frac1{6\pi}\cos(3\pi t)\sin(3\pi t)+\frac t2\right)'=cos^2(3\pi t).$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u=3 \pi t$
$$\frac {1}{3 \pi} \int cos^2(u) \mathrm{d}u=\frac {1}{3 \pi} \int \frac12 \cos(2u)+\frac12 \mathrm{d}u=\frac {1}{6 \pi} \left (\int \cos(2u) \mathrm{d}u+\int 1 \mathrm{d}u \right ) \stackrel{s=2u}{=}\frac{sin(s)}{12 \pi}+\frac{u}{6 \pi}+c=\frac{6 \pi t+\sin(6 \pi t)}{12 \pi}+c$$
Insert the limits of integration, apply the FTC and you get $$\int_{-1}^{1} \cos^2(3 \pi t) \mathrm{d}t=1$$

It would be neater to have the limits of integration from the start, but I evaluated the antiderivative by mistake, and went with that.